# error: cannot combine with previous 'type-name' declaration specifier

Tags: android, c++, unicode

The error:

```
In file included from /path/to/include/utils/String16.h:22:
/path/to/include/utils/Unicode.h:25:18: error: cannot combine with previous 'type-name' declaration specifier
typedef uint32_t char32_t;
                 ^
/path/to/include/utils/Unicode.h:25:1: warning: typedef requires a name [-Wmissing-declarations]
typedef uint32_t char32_t;
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/path/to/include/utils/Unicode.h:26:18: error: cannot combine with previous 'type-name' declaration specifier
typedef uint16_t char16_t;
                 ^
/path/to/include/utils/Unicode.h:26:1: warning: typedef requires a name [-Wmissing-declarations]
typedef uint16_t char16_t;
```

The related file Unicode.h:

```
    /*
 * Copyright (C) 2005 The Android Open Source Project
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

#ifndef ANDROID_UNICODE_H
#define ANDROID_UNICODE_H

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdint.h>

extern "C" {

typedef uint32_t char32_t;
typedef uint16_t char16_t;

// Standard string functions on char16_t strings.
int strcmp16(const char16_t *, const char16_t *);
int strncmp16(const char16_t *s1, const char16_t *s2, size_t n);
size_t strlen16(const char16_t *);
size_t strnlen16(const char16_t *, size_t);
char16_t *strcpy16(char16_t *, const char16_t *);
char16_t *strncpy16(char16_t *, const char16_t *, size_t);

// Version of comparison that supports embedded nulls.
// This is different than strncmp() because we don't stop
// at a nul character and consider the strings to be different
// if the lengths are different (thus we need to supply the
// lengths of both strings).  This can also be used when
// your string is not nul-terminated as it will have the
// equivalent result as strcmp16 (unlike strncmp16).
int strzcmp16(const char16_t *s1, size_t n1, const char16_t *s2, size_t n2);

// Version of strzcmp16 for comparing strings in different endianness.
int strzcmp16_h_n(const char16_t *s1H, size_t n1, const char16_t *s2N, size_t n2);

// Standard string functions on char32_t strings.
size_t strlen32(const char32_t *);
size_t strnlen32(const char32_t *, size_t);

/**
 * Measure the length of a UTF-32 string in UTF-8. If the string is invalid
 * such as containing a surrogate character, -1 will be returned.
 */
ssize_t utf32_to_utf8_length(const char32_t *src, size_t src_len);

/**
 * Stores a UTF-8 string converted from "src" in "dst", if "dst_length" is not
 * large enough to store the string, the part of the "src" string is stored
 * into "dst" as much as possible. See the examples for more detail.
 * Returns the size actually used for storing the string.
 * dst" is not null-terminated when dst_len is fully used (like strncpy).
 *
 * Example 1
 * "src" == \u3042\u3044 (\xE3\x81\x82\xE3\x81\x84)
 * "src_len" == 2
 * "dst_len" >= 7
 * ->
 * Returned value == 6
 * "dst" becomes \xE3\x81\x82\xE3\x81\x84\0
 * (note that "dst" is null-terminated)
 *
 * Example 2
 * "src" == \u3042\u3044 (\xE3\x81\x82\xE3\x81\x84)
 * "src_len" == 2
 * "dst_len" == 5
 * ->
 * Returned value == 3
 * "dst" becomes \xE3\x81\x82\0
 * (note that "dst" is null-terminated, but \u3044 is not stored in "dst"
 * since "dst" does not have enough size to store the character)
 *
 * Example 3
 * "src" == \u3042\u3044 (\xE3\x81\x82\xE3\x81\x84)
 * "src_len" == 2
 * "dst_len" == 6
 * ->
 * Returned value == 6
 * "dst" becomes \xE3\x81\x82\xE3\x81\x84
 * (note that "dst" is NOT null-terminated, like strncpy)
 */
void utf32_to_utf8(const char32_t* src, size_t src_len, char* dst);

/**
 * Returns the unicode value at "index".
 * Returns -1 when the index is invalid (equals to or more than "src_len").
 * If returned value is positive, it is able to be converted to char32_t, which
 * is unsigned. Then, if "next_index" is not NULL, the next index to be used is
 * stored in "next_index". "next_index" can be NULL.
 */
int32_t utf32_from_utf8_at(const char *src, size_t src_len, size_t index, size_t *next_index);


/**
 * Returns the UTF-8 length of UTF-16 string "src".
 */
ssize_t utf16_to_utf8_length(const char16_t *src, size_t src_len);

/**
 * Converts a UTF-16 string to UTF-8. The destination buffer must be large
 * enough to fit the UTF-16 as measured by utf16_to_utf8_length with an added
 * NULL terminator.
 */
void utf16_to_utf8(const char16_t* src, size_t src_len, char* dst);

/**
 * Returns the length of "src" when "src" is valid UTF-8 string.
 * Returns 0 if src is NULL or 0-length string. Returns -1 when the source
 * is an invalid string.
 *
 * This function should be used to determine whether "src" is valid UTF-8
 * characters with valid unicode codepoints. "src" must be null-terminated.
 *
 * If you are going to use other utf8_to_... functions defined in this header
 * with string which may not be valid UTF-8 with valid codepoint (form 0 to
 * 0x10FFFF), you should use this function before calling others, since the
 * other functions do not check whether the string is valid UTF-8 or not.
 *
 * If you do not care whether "src" is valid UTF-8 or not, you should use
 * strlen() as usual, which should be much faster.
 */
ssize_t utf8_length(const char *src);

/**
 * Measure the length of a UTF-32 string.
 */
size_t utf8_to_utf32_length(const char *src, size_t src_len);

/**
 * Stores a UTF-32 string converted from "src" in "dst". "dst" must be large
 * enough to store the entire converted string as measured by
 * utf8_to_utf32_length plus space for a NULL terminator.
 */
void utf8_to_utf32(const char* src, size_t src_len, char32_t* dst);

/**
 * Returns the UTF-16 length of UTF-8 string "src".
 */
ssize_t utf8_to_utf16_length(const uint8_t* src, size_t srcLen);

/**
 * Convert UTF-8 to UTF-16 including surrogate pairs.
 * Returns a pointer to the end of the string (where a null terminator might go
 * if you wanted to add one).
 */
char16_t* utf8_to_utf16_no_null_terminator(const uint8_t* src, size_t srcLen, char16_t* dst);

/**
 * Convert UTF-8 to UTF-16 including surrogate pairs. The destination buffer
 * must be large enough to hold the result as measured by utf8_to_utf16_length
 * plus an added NULL terminator.
 */
void utf8_to_utf16(const uint8_t* src, size_t srcLen, char16_t* dst);

}

#endif
```

My compiling environment:

> macOS 10.13
>
> Android studio 3.1.2 + gradle + ndk
>
> Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)
>
> cFlags "-frtti -fexceptions -std=c++11"

I'm compiling some ndk method. In fact some c++ binder class and method.In my handcraft cpp file ,I need include some .h file located in android platforms source code path.I downloaded the source code form android.googlesource.com.When I begin gradle task to compile the whole project ,error thrown by ndk build.And I cannot find any second typedef name of uint32_t or uint16_t.Why the error occured?

Comment: I'm guessing its a problem because C++11 standard added the types `char16_t` and `char32_t` types, and the Android definitions clashes with the C++ standard definitions.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude You're right.I found another char32_t typedef name at file /path/to/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/__config,line 320,code here `#if __cplusplus < 201103L
typedef __char16_t char16_t;
typedef __char32_t char32_t;
#endif`

Comment: And I test `__cplusplus` macro value use my system terminal via g++,return `199711`.But when I compile with -std=c++11 ,it returns `201103`.So it seems when I ndk-build run,the -std=c++11 didn't work.

Comment: But I set the `-std=c++11` at three places:1.build.gradle fine `android.defaultConfig.ndk.cFlags`2.Android.mk `LOCAL_CFLAGS += -std=c++11` 3.Application.mk `APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -fexceptions -std=c++11`,but the error still come.

Comment: I just found not only one place typedef char32_t,the ndk-bundle folder must define at least one char32_t.So I just cannot make this error gone.No way?!But I need compile a c++ binder service implementation.What should I do

Comment: @Eilir when compiling for C++11 and later, `char16_t` and `char32_t` are **native types** in the C++ language, just like `char` and `wchar_t` are. Your NDK is manually defining `char16_t`/`char32_t` only when NOT compiling for C++11 or later, that is what the `#if __cplusplus < 201103L` is checking for.  Your compiler also clearly has its own `__char16_t` and `__char32_t` types as non-standard extensions.  I would suggest modifying `Unicode.h` to wrap the `char16_t`/`char32_t` typedefs in a similar `#if` block so it uses the native types when compiling for C++11 and later.

Comment: But the Unicode.h wasn't written by me?That's included in a version of android/platform/native source code!I download it and use it just because I have imitate a file written basic on an example from android/aidl sample here `android.googlesource.com/platform/system/tools/aidl/+/brillo-m10-dev/tests/`,this source code contains an implementation of aidl parcelable class written by c++,named simple_parcelable.h(or .cpp).I imitate that style to write my own parcelable c++ class.In that implementation,it includes the binder/Parcelable header file,includes String16,includes Unicode.

Comment: Because aidl-cpp commandline cannot generate a parcelable aidl class.I have to imitate the sample.But obviously,the sample were out of date.The dependence among these files, cannot find in latest code.The version of code I used is named `native-jb-mr1.1-dev`, it should be a long ago version.

Comment: the `native-jb-mr1.1-dev` comes from here `android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/native/+/jb-mr1.1-dev/include/utils/String16.h` I google searched `utils/String16.h`,it's the first result.

Comment: I abandoned using the `native-jb-mr1.1-dev` include,instead of `platform/system/core` from here `android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/android-o-mr1-iot-release-1.0.1`I the error about Unicode.h has gone.I seem to mistake the include file.I shouldn't download the first result from google search ,that's a mistake.Now I compile my project,a new error is cannot find file `utils/Errors.h`,but I'm sure it sit in the `core` include path.